# (Python) Running python script in command line - can't access URLs from internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-interface

I created a python script that scrapes text from an article online if I have the article URL. I created this script in anaconda (spyder) and the script runs with no problems and returns all the text for each article.

I tried to run the script from the command line, and it looks like it is running correctly, but when I open the file at the end there is no text from the website. I can tell there is no connection to the internet because if there is no connection when doing the get request, the text returned is "No Connection" for that website.

Why would this script work when I run it in Anaconda (spyder), but not connect to to the internet from the command line?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Im assuming your environment is not restricted (ie school computer) ? right?

Comment: what CLI are you using? Try executing `ping google.com` on your command line and see if that passes

Comment: google.com works. Not restricted.I tried using Git Bash and also just the regular command prompt (cmd). I then tried the Anaconda prompt and it looks like it is now connecting to the internet. Is it possible that the packages I installed under Anaconda are the reason that the command line and git bash don't connect? I'm new to executing things in the command line - I always just run things through Anaconda